# tkinter returns "no such file or directory" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

logoImage = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
logoLabel = Label(root, image=logoImage, bg='dodgerblue3')
logoLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

The image is in the same directory as the project. In fact, when I open it with cmd or Python it works. But when I use VS Code or Turn it into .exe file, it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Simo\OneDrive\Python\Scientific calculator\calc.py", line 180, in <module>
    logoImage = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
  File "C:\Users\Simo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Simo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "logo.png": no such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can always check manually if the file really exists by `import os; print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))` before using relative path.

Comment: It's looking in your current working directory, which may not be the same directory that the script is in.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try putting the file into your workspace and using the relative path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).